# Telling Emacs to mark \iffalse...\fi blocks?

Tags: emacs

Do you know a simple way to tell GNU Emacs to recognize LaTeX `\iffalse ... \fi` blocks and to display them in a special way, e.g., using a lighter font, or using font-lock-comment-face. Is there a LaTeX style package that already knows how to do this?

I understand that correctly recognizing valid `\iffalse's` and their matching `\fi's` in arbitrary LaTeX source file is a non-trivial problem, but I am happy with an approximate solution that works in most easy cases, e.g., that assumes no nesting of `\if\fi's` and requires these commands to appear alone on their source line.

Comment: I've little idea how to do this, but I believe AUCTeX would could/would be useful here---is its use allowed, or should it stick to normal `tex-mode`?

Comment: A solution with AUCTeX is fine with me.

Answer (score 7):

This solution does not require AUCTeX to the best of my knowledge.

Add the following to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(
      ("\\\\iffalse\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\\)\\\\fi" 1 font-lock-comment-face)))))
```

[image: result]